# Understanding default arguments in range and list slicing in Python

Tags: python, windows

Good day. I don’t entirely understand this code.
I understand that the syntax for range is `range(start, stop, step/stride)`. And that the default arguments are `range(start = 0, stop=, step= 1)`, so what I understand from your code is:
`for i in range(len(list) - 1, -1, -1):`
is that the index `(i)` should start at `len(lst) - 1`, because you want to start at the index of end of the list, which would be `len(list) - 1`, because in a list of 10 elements it would be index 9, as index starts from zero.
I also understand the step/stride portion, because we want `i` to iterate backwards from the last index.

But what I do not understand is why the end argument is `-1`, which is at the end of the list. Since we are iterating backwards, shouldn't it end at the start of the list, which should be zero? That is the portion I don’t understand. Please can you shed more light on this?

Sorry to bother you again but I also don’t fully understand the list slice.
I know the syntax for list slicing is `list[start : stop : step]`, I understand the step or stride portion and I know the default arguments are `list[start= 0 : stop = -1 and step =1]`. I understand the step part since we want to iterate backwards when using `list[: : -1]`.

What I don’t understand, is how python knows to start at the end of the list since the default argument is still `-1` or is it because `0-1=-1` so it starts from the end?

Furthermore, how does it know to end at the beginning rather than at `-1`, which is the default argument?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What code are you talking about? ("This Code")

Comment: @Honn I think OP is asking how slices are implemented?

Comment: @Honn wa trying to get a better understanding of this:                                       
There are a few ways that you can iterate over a list backward.,

for i in range(len(list)-1, -1, -1):
  ...
Another way to iterate over a list backward is to utilize list slicing, with a negative step. This will return a new list of elements in reverse order.

for i in list[::-1]:

Comment: @goonerlabs So the question is how those are different?

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges):

> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.

`r[i] > stop` means that `stop` will never be part of the sequence. Thus, to end the range at 0, the first index, you have to wrie `range(len(list)-1, -1, -1)`, where the second argument is one `step` further than the last element you want to be included in the range.
For example `range(5, 0, -1)` contains `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`, since it stops when the next element (0) would have been smaller or equal to the second argument (0).

Why list slicing works the way it does is just because that is how the python interpreter was made to understand it. You can think of negative indexes as normal indexes but backwards (starting at -1, not -0).

`[1, 2, 3, 4][-1:0:-1]` does not work for reversing the list, since it stops one element before index 0, returning `[4,3,2]`, and `[1,2,3,4][-1:-1:-1]` does not work since the first element is the element to stop at, so the returned list is empty. If you omit `start` or `stop`, the slice just includes the rest of the list in that direction (`[1,2,3,4][1:] == [2,3,4]` and `[1,2,3,4][:3] == [1,2,3]`). Thus there is another way to reverse the order of lists in python: `[1,2,3,4][::-1]`.